# Merge two NumPy arrays into one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mask

Say I have the following two arrays, `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 0],
             [1, 1]],

            [[1, 0],
             [0, 0]],

            [[0, 0],
             [1, 0]]])

b = np.array([[[0, 2],
             [0, 0]],

            [[0, 0],
             [0, 2]],

            [[0, 2],
             [0, 2]]])
```

and I wish to 'overlap' them so that I get the following result:

```
          [[[1, 2],
            [1, 1]],

           [[1, 0],
            [0, 2]],

           [[0, 2],
            [1, 2]]]
```

In the case there is an overlapping co-ordinate, I would just take `1`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe `a + b[a == 0]`

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample data does not include all cases to verify the expected requirements. Solutions that only deliver the expected result in certain cases go unnoticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can start with a matrix with zeros and then assign the flags one by one:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 0],
               [1, 1]],
              [[1, 0],
               [0, 0]],
              [[0, 0],
               [1, 0]]])
b = np.array([[[0, 2],
               [0, 0]],
              [[0, 0],
               [0, 2]],
              [[0, 2],
               [0, 2]]])
# Create a matrix with zeros
c = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype='int')
# Assign flags
c[b==2] = 2
c[a==1] = 1 # Put in second because priority to 1 in case of overlapping
# Output
print(c)
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[0, 2],
        [1, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple sum I manage to get the desired result:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 0],
             [1, 1]],

            [[1, 0],
             [0, 0]],

            [[0, 0],
             [1, 0]]])

b = np.array([[[0, 2],
             [0, 0]],

            [[0, 0],
             [0, 2]],

            [[0, 2],
             [0, 2]]])

print(a+b)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2]
  [1 1]]

 [[1 0]
  [0 2]]

 [[0 2]
  [1 2]]]
```

Comment: Be careful, in the case there is an overlapping co-ordinate, you will get `1+2=3` instead of `1`